Video does not accept the height of its parent
<style>
.gl {
    width: 50%;
}
.pl {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50vh;
    background: red;
}
video {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<div class='gl'>
    <div class='pl'>
    <video  src='/1111.mp4'></video>
    </div>
</div>


The aspect ratio of the video may vary. Tall, narrow, wide and tall, etc...
In my example, the problem is that the video ignores the maximum width limit max-height: 50vh;
Logically, the video is aligned horizontally, but its height extends beyond the red canvas.
In this case, how can I force the video to adhere to the maximum height of the parent?

The problem is that you are not defining a height for p1 (max-height does not count)  therefore 100% height for the video will not mean anything. There are a couple of ways around this, e.g. setting p1 to display:flex but I think it would be easier just to set your max-height and max-width on the video element instead - does this do what you want?

This question is similar to: CSS video not stretching to 100% width of parent container. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
